# HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized

Tags: curl, azure-iot-dps

Below curl request throwing follwoing errors, any help here?

Thanks,
Pradeep

curl -i -L -X PUT -cert ./certs/new-devices.cert.pem -key ./private/new-devices.key.pem -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -H 'Content-Encoding:utf-8' -d '{"registrationId":"sensor-thl-2001"}' https://global.azure-devices-provisioning.net/One00xxx/registrations/sensor-thl-2001/register?api-version=2019-03-31

curl: (6) Could not resolve host: .
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: .
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized

Comment: Did you check the troubleshooting guide for common problems and resolutions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-troubleshoot-error-401003-iothubunauthorized

Comment: Thanks but thats not that useful because, I am facing issue with the iot-dps.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are configuring your Authorization HTTP header with a valid `Bearer Token`. In order to get it you first need to create a Service Principal in your Azure Tenant as very well documented here: [How to call Azure REST APIs with curl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/#how-to-call-azure-rest-apis-with-curl)